# Will installing Egit interfere with existing Git installation?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have been working with Git from the command-line for a few weeks. I am now on a project that uses Eclipse as the IDE and [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) for the Git plugin. I am worried that by installing EGit I'm going to destroy any Git configs in my existing projects (that I've been maintaining/coding directly from a terminal).

If EGit could interfere, how so (and how can I avoid this)? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesnt interfere. EGit only works within Eclipse and is independent from a command line Git installation. Regarding the configuration EGit of course reads your existing gitconfig. But if you use a recent Git version on the command line, there shouldn't be any differences in the config.

In fact you can keep using Git on the command line for committing, pushing etc. It doesn't matter if the project is configured for EGit in Eclipse.