# Using EGit and git simultaneously

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea, egit

Currently I'm developing on Windows with Java using Eclipse and EGit installed and everything works fine. However, I'd like to try the IntelliJ IDEA where the IDE required the git.exe to work with Git. Thus, I installed git v1.9.2 from http://git-scm.com/. Everything works fine in IDEA, but in Eclipse some file are marked as "changed" (having the ">" symbol prepended) although there is absolutely nothing that changed. My bet is that there is that EGit and git interfere with each other. But unfortunately I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: What version of EGit are you using? What does `git config core.filemode` print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the two should not interfere with each other.

See the answer here:

> [Will installing Egit interfere with existing Git installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203843/will-installing-egit-interfere-with-existing-git-installation)